# Java Imaging Framework

Tags: java, image-processing, frameworks

Is there any Open source or Commercial Java frameworks for doing image operations such as converting the images from one format to other and scaling the images etc.

There should be no installation.Set of jars that are in classpath that will do the job.

I have looked into the **java-image-scaling** library but it is having issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do most of these operations in Java natively using [JAI](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/).  You can also use Swing Graphics2D to do any manipulation required.

Comment: I tried JAI also. It is having issues when generating thumbnails from gif and other formats.

Comment: It is, or you are?  Be specific and maybe we can help.

Comment: I know that I've had to use some 3rd party classes for animated gif support, but it should be able to handle regular gif just fine.

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick is the best framework for doing the kind of things you're taking about and you can use JMagick or Im4java to wrap its usage, but it does require the installation of ImageMagick.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Catalano Framework](http://code.google.com/p/catalano-framework/). It is extreme easily. You can run the same code in Android as well. There is a lot algorithm in parallel.
Example: Resize image.

```
FastBitmap fb = new FastBitmap(pathname);

//You can choose interpolation algorithm too.
Resize r = new Resize();
r.applyInPlace(fb);
```